# Optimization problem matrix with non-linear objective

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have an optimization problem with one non-linear objective and linear constraints.

The variable to optimize is a matrix *A* that represents the amounts of money that will be invested by each portfolio (*m*) on each of the products (*n*) (so each row represents one portfolio and each column represents one available product):

[image: matrix]

- There is a vector *a<sub>p0</sub>* that tell us for each *n* (portfolio) an already invested amount.
- There is a vector *y*<sub>*p0*</sub> that tell us for each *n* (portfolio) an average interest of the already invested amount.
- There is a vector *a<sub>p</sub>* that tells us for each *n* (portfolio) a total amount available.
- There is a vector *y<sub>L</sub>* that tell us for each *m* (product) an interest rate.
- There is a vector *a<sub>L</sub>* that tells us for each *m* (product) a total amount available.

[image: vectors]

- We have a *y<sub>target</sub>* that we want the portfolios to be as close as possible to.

We want to populate the *A* (Amount matrix) so that all portfolios get as close as possible to *y<sub>target</sub>*.

So, our objective is to make the sum of the differences between the weighted average of the portfolio projected yields and the *y<sub>target</sub>* as small as possible.

[image: objective]

We have three constraints:

The sum of all the investment for each investor must be smaller than the total amount available for that investor.

[image: constraint1]

The sum of all the investment for each product must be equal to the value of that product.

[image: constraint2]

Investment on each product per portfolio must be smaller than X.

[image: constraint3]

To solve this problem so far, I have tried:
 - PuLP python library - didn’t work as the objective function holds a non-linear relation)
- scipy.optimize which is what I am trying a the moment. However, there are challenges I don’t know if I am ever going to be able to overcome in it.

Demo version with code:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np
import random

n = 100
m = 5000

a_p0 = np.random.rand(1,m)*100000
y_p0 = np.random.rand(1,m)*4
a_p = np.random.rand(1,m)*10000
y_l = np.random.rand(1,n)*4
a_l = np.random.rand(1,n)*2000

y_target = random.random()*4

A = scipy.rand(n, m)*10

y_target = random

row = n
col = m

#optimize doesn't accept matrices so I transform it to a vector    
def toVector(w):
    return np.hstack(w)

def toMat(vec, row, col):
    return vec[:row*col].reshape(row,col)


def cons_loans_amt(v):
    A = toMat(v,row, col)
    return A.sum(axis=1) - a_l

def constrain_invst_amt(v):
    A = toMat(v,row, col)
    return a_p - A.sum(axis=0)

cons = [{'type':'eq', 'fun': cons_loans_amt},
        {'type':'ineq', 'fun': constrain_invst_amt}]

def objective(v):
    A = toMat(v,row, col)
    diff = 0
    for m in range(A.shape[1]):
        opt_up = (y_p0[0][m] * a_p0[0][m]) + np.dot(y_l, A[m])
        opt_down = a_p0[0][m] + A[m].sum()
        diff += ((opt_up/opt_down) - y_target)**2
    return diff.sum()

#This is the code I am running at the moment with a memory error.
x0 = scipy.rand(row, col)
x0 = toVector(x0)
optimize.minimize(objective, x0, constraints=cons, method='SLSQP')
```

At the moment I am blocked I am getting a memory error and not sure if I am working in the right path.

Could anyone help me assess:

1. If this optimization problem is feasible to solve
2. If the approach I am taking is correct

Thank you.

Comment: scipy.optimize is for small/medium sized problems only. For large problems you may want to look into large scale, sparse solvers. Not sure if this problem is convex. If it is, CVXPY may help with the modeling. This objective is not clear to me (dividing by a vector?)

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen You are right the notation was wrong. It is divided by the sum of the values of the column m in the matrix. I have edited the question to fix this. I will also give a try to CVXPY. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure this problem is convex (if not CVXPY will not apply).